# Redirect root domain with https to subfolder with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I am trying to point the main domain from my host (https://website.com) which right now just goes to public_html to a subfolder in the public_html directory (new.website.com) with the user still seeing https://website.com without changing.

I tried doing what is found in here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

And added this code to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new.website.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new.website.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ new.website.com/index.php [L]
```

However 2 things happened incorrectly:

1. The domain changed to https://new.website.com/404.html
2. It is giving me a page to proceed with caution since new.website.com does not have a certificate.

(folder name and also a subdomain are both named: new.website.com)

How can i redirect so it still shows https://website.com and go to the wordpress folder?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you need to have website.com visible to the public but actually, WordPress is installed on new.website.com

In this case, you need to do Wordpress multisite.

Check: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network